# Making a 2D sprite move in a curved jump in Unity

Tags: unity, tweening, ngui

Given a 2D Sprite (I'm using NGUI if it matters), what is the simplest way to move it to another position using a curve that resembles a jump?

[image]

When I used `cocos2d`, there was an action called `JumpTo` which basically tweened the sprite to a particular position. It had parameters for curve height and speed and such.

How can I achieve this in Unity? I have the `DOTween` plugin if it helps (although I don't think it does this).

I don't have a predefined path for the sprite to follow either. I only want it to behave like `cocos2d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to the [DOTween documentation](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php)
2. Scroll down to the Move section.
3. Click on DOJump to expand that explanation.

[image]

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah, my `DOTween` was outdated and didn't have those methods.

Comment: this is amazing ....

Comment: also, you can reverse the curve of the jump by negative jump power